# How many/which/is there a listing somewhere of the 3rd-party R packages that are parallelized in Revolution Enterprise?

Tags: revolution-r

Can I use packages like forecast, nnet, ets, etc, on Revolution Enterprise, in a way that lets me take advantage of Revolution's unique approach to parallelization?  Is there some list of which packages let me take advantage of this?

Does my question reflect some central misconception of what exactly Revolution provides that can be addressed instead (I ask this last part because, if the answer is no, what is the point of Revolution in the first place?)?